# If statement in knockout.js not working as expected

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I'm trying to display the string "No data was found." inside a table row whenever the data array is empty, but it seems the message get always printed no matter what.

[Reproduction online](http://jsfiddle.net/fxhkszmx/5/) (ignoring the condition `orders.length ==0`)

What am I doing wrong?

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Truck</th>
            <th>Pickup</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <!-- ko if: orders.length==2 -->
    <tbody>
        <tr colspan="2">No data was found.</tr>
    </tbody>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: orders">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: truck"></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `orders` is an `ko.observableArray` you need to write `orders()` to get the underlying array and get the length from there:

```
<!-- ko if: orders().length== 0 -->
```

Your HTML also invalid, the `td` elements are missing from:

```
<!-- ko if: orders().length==0 -->
    <tbody data-bind="if: orders().length==0">
        <tr colspan="2"><td>No data was found.</td></tr>
    </tbody>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/43kgxaov/).

Comment: I changed it, but it's not doign what I expected. Seems to be doing the contrary:  http://jsfiddle.net/fxhkszmx/6/

Comment: @Alvaro Your fiddle has a couple of issues.  "No data was found" is not in a `<td>` so ends up in the wrong place, and your assignment of the data is not correct - it should just be `self.orders(data);` - no need for `=`.  [See this version](http://jsfiddle.net/fxhkszmx/8/)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistakes! I'll accept the answer in 3 mins.